# Nested case statement in Data Studio

Tags: dashboard, looker-studio

I have campaign names as "08-2019 ABCD - Compass" , "09-2019-DEFG Compass ebook" from which I would like to separate part of string but there is no pattern to separate the data.

I tried to write a nested case statement to create a new dimension by checking for "Compass" first and later "Compass ebook" but it throws up error as Invalid formula.

```
CASE 
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign Name,"^.*(Compass).*") THEN 
   CASE 
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign Name,"^.*(Compass eBook).*") THEN "Compass eBook"
    ELSE "Compass"
   END
ELSE "Undefined" End
```

How do I achieve nested case statement scenario in Google data studio while creating a new dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement below does the trick ([Linking both posts](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/42921661?msgid=42942243)):

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign Name, ".*(?i)(Compass eBook).*") THEN "Compass eBook"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign Name, ".*(?i)(Compass).*") THEN "Compass"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign Name, ".*(?i)(Testing Test).*") THEN "Testing Test"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign Name, ".*(?i)(API Blockade Pattern).*") THEN "API Blockade Pattern"
  ELSE "Undefined"
END
```

The Case statement uses a "*First In First Out*" type approach, thus setting the first `WHEN` clause to `Compass eBook` ensures that when [`REGEXP_MATCH`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7064476) sees the phrase `Compass eBook` it will be displayed first over the second [`REGEXP_MATCH`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7064476) that looks for `Compass`

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/8d41b9df-7873-457b-99d5-dbf6d1f51cea) to elaborate:

[image]